# Get text from mixed element xml tags with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using ElementTree to parse an XML document that I have. I am getting the text from the `u` tags. Some of them have mixed content that I need to filter out or keep as text. Two examples that I have are:

```
<u>
   <vocal type="filler">
     <desc>eh</desc>
   </vocal>¿Sí? 
</u>

<u>Pues... 
   <vocal type="non-ling">
     <desc>laugh</desc>
   </vocal>A mí no me suena. 
</u>
```

I want to get the text within the vocal tag if it's type is `filler` but not if it's type is `non-ling`.

If I iterate through the children of `u`, somehow the last text bit is always lost. The only way that I can reach it is by using `itertext()`. But then the chance to check the type of the vocal tag is lost.

How can I parse it so that I get a result like this:

```
eh ¿Sí? 
Pues... A mí no me suena.
```

Comment: You'll have to iterate over all child nodes and text nodes "manually" (i.e. without using `itertext()`) and filter out what you don't need.  Alternatively you could preprocess the XML with a simple XSLT transform to remove the subtrees you don't want.

Comment: When I iterate manually the last text bit is always lost.

Comment: Show the code you're using to iterate manually.  It's probably recursive, are you remembering to continue iterating after the recursive call to capture following text nodes?

Comment: `for t in u_element.iter(): print(t.text)` -> This only prints "eh" in the first and "Pues...laugh" in the second `u` element. Not sure I know how to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lost text bits, "¿Sí?" and "A mí no me suena.", are available as the [`tail`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) property of each `<vocal>` element (the text following the element's end tag).

Here is a way to get the wanted output (tested with Python 2.7).

Assume that vocal.xml looks like this:

```
<root>
  <u>
    <vocal type="filler">
      <desc>eh</desc>
    </vocal>¿Sí? 
  </u>

  <u>Pues... 
     <vocal type="non-ling">
       <desc>laugh</desc>
     </vocal>A mí no me suena. 
  </u>
</root>
```

Code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("vocal.xml") 

for u in root.findall(".//u"):
    v = u.find("vocal")

    if v.get("type") == "filler":
        frags = [u.text, v.findtext("desc"), v.tail]
    else:
        frags = [u.text, v.tail]

    print " ".join(t.encode("utf-8").strip() for t in frags).strip()
```

Output:

```
eh ¿Sí?
Pues... A mí no me suena.
```