# custom lxml TreeBuilder with mixed tags and text

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I want to use the lxml lib to transform xml to dict.
But i have semi structured XML, like : 
`<doc>This is<i>xmlobj</i> documentation.<b> SUPER</b> great</doc>`

if i do :

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import time

my_file = "aaa.xml"


def etree_to_dict(t):
    d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
    children = list(t)
    if children:
        dd = defaultdict(list)
        for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
            for k, v in dc.items():
                dd[k].append(v)
        d = {t.tag: {k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v
                     for k, v in dd.items()}}
    if t.attrib:
        d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v)
                        for k, v in t.attrib.items())
    if t.text:
        text = t.text.strip()
        if children or t.attrib:
            if text:
              d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
        else:
            d[t.tag] = text
    return d

from lxml import etree as ET

count = 0
p=True

tree = ET.parse(my_file)
root = tree.getroot()
#iter = root.iter('PubmedArticle')
iter = root.iter('example')

for entry in iter:
    count+= 1
    if p:
      p=False
      r = etree_to_dict(entry)
      print(r)

print(count)
```

i get :

```
{'example': {'doc': {'i': 'xmlobj', 'b': 'SUPER', '#text': 'This is'}, 'a': 'Oui'}}
```

"great" is missing

i'v tried to implement my own treebuilder :

```
from lxml import etree as ET


parser = ET.XMLParser( target = myTreeBuilder())
tree = ET.parse(my_file,parser)


r = etree_to_dict(tree)
```

but i don't understand how i should implement it.

the default TreeBuilder is there : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py

Comment: Can you share the `xml` file?

Comment: its just a file with <doc>This is<i>xmlobj</i> documentation.<b> SUPER</b> great</doc>

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary

Comment: yeah, it returns :" {'i': 'xmlobj', 'b': ' SUPER'}", so text is still missing
and xmltodict lib doesn't keep the order of the text, thus rendering it unusable in my case

Comment: @The_Pingu_ *"implement my own treebuilder"*: Wrong direction, you don't want to **build** a xml tree, you want to parse it. Go with [`iterparse`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#event-driven-parsing)

Comment: The missing "great" string is the `tail` of the `<b>` element. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47300760/407651.